# Android MediaPlayer "stop called in state 0 (Error -38,0)" with prepare called

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play some audio in my application, and I keep getting the error:

```
E/MediaPlayer: stop called in state 1
V/MediaPlayer: message received msg=100, ext1=-38, ext2=0
E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
```

I have checked many other answers, but all say that you need to call prepareAsync() or prepare() to prevent this, but in my case I have, and I still get the error. I have also tried with both, and they didn't stop the error. This is my code:

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(message.getVoice());
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

I have no clue why this isn't working, all of it is surrounded in a try catch block, and it is giving me no hints either. The audio file is received from a server, and I can confirm that it is not returning null.

Comment: what `message.getVoice()` return type?

Comment: message.getVoice() is a string

Comment: also check the filePath string, what you are getting in it?

Comment: I cannot give you the URL, but it is correct and I can visit it on my browser

Comment: so you are trying to play it online...

Comment: have you added the Internet permission in manifest?

Comment: Yes, internet permission is in the manifest, everything is in place to get this audio and play it, it is just this error that I am getting, not a permission error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason, changing where the onPreparedListener was fixed everything:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
```

Then inheriting the method and using:

```
@Override
public void onPrepared() {
    Do stuff
}
```

This shouldn't have done anything, but in my case it worked.

Comment: What do you mean "changing where the onPreparedListener was fixed everything"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the dataSource like this..

```
  MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(message.getVoice()));
    player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This does the exact same thing as my code, but it is just a longer way of doing it. This method returns the same errors, as it wouldn't do otherwise.

Comment: than paste the whole media player class here.

Comment: I am using the default media player class, and you have all my code related to it apart from the declaration of the instance.

Comment: did you try to start with `mp.start();` instead of `mediaPlayer.start();`?

Comment: It wouldn't make a difference, they are both referencing the same media player instance.

Comment: than i will suggest you to add each line(AudioStream,DataSource,prepare) with a try catch Or debug which statement is causing the problem.

Comment: They are already in a try catch, I get no line numbers. Debugger did nothing and showed nothing.

Comment: you said ["and you have all my code related to it apart from the declaration of the instance"] , but i can't see the try catch block..Can you mention the full code.. Or it is against your security.

Comment: You can see everything you need to see. As you have to have `mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Uri)` in a try catch, I though that you would assume that the rest is.